# getline into char** yields only the last line

Tags: c, getline

I'm trying to store the line from getline(..., line, ...) into char** array.
But when I iterate through the array to print the lines, it only prints the last line.
I think there's something in the man that I missed.

[the input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlq4a.png)

[standard output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf61R.png)

```
int fill_map(t_args *args)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    args->maze = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t nread;

    args->maze = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    for (size_t j = 0; (nread = getline(&line, &len, args->stream)) != -1; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            args->width = (int)nread;
        args->maze = realloc(args->maze, sizeof(char *) * (i + 1));
        args->maze[i] = line;
    }
    args->height = i;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (size_t)args->height; i++)
    {
        printf("%ld %s", i, args->maze[i]);
    }

    return nread;
}
```

Comment: You’re not copying the line you read, you just copy its pointer. The pointer is always the same, and its content is overwritten by every `getline` operation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  If he's lucky.  Worst case `line` was reallocated along the way and at least some of the pointers are completely invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is reusing the buffer `line` for reading, and `getline` only reallocates it if its size is too small to fit the next line to read (and, in that cases, `free`s the previous buffer!). As a consequence, successive lines will be stored in the same buffer, at the same address, which is assigned to `maze[i]`.

To avoid this, you can reset `line` and `len` before each call to `getline`:

```
for (size_t j = 0; (nread = getline(&line, &len, args->stream)) != -1; i++)
{
    if (i == 1)
        args->width = (int)nread;
    args->maze = realloc(args->maze, sizeof(char *) * (i + 1));
    args->maze[i] = line;
    line = NULL;
    len = 0;
}

free(line); // Important!
```

Note that we need to `free(line)` after the last `getline` call, even though that call failed.

In addition I would protest this abuse of the `for` loop, though this is certainly a matter of style: since you’re not really iterating over the same variable that you’re declaring and updating, I’d separate the file reading and looping over `i` (and what’s the point of `j` anyway?), and use a `while` loop; this also makes the usage of `i` simpler (no `i + 1` necessary):

```
while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, args->stream)) != -1) {
    ++i;
    args->width = (int) nread;
    args->maze = realloc(args->maze, sizeof(char *) * i);
    args->maze[i] = line;
    line = NULL;
    len = 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to free line in the loop... needless to say it did crash, 
The answer was line = NULL, 
close.

Thanks alot (:

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for every line as well. Then you need to copy the line.

```
    args->maze = realloc(args->maze, sizeof(char *) * (i + 1));
    args -> maze[i] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
    strcpy(args->maze[i], line);
```

Comment: No need to compute `strlen(line)`, which is redundant and costly: use `nread `.

Comment: @KonradRudolph it does not matter as it shows the IDEA not the IMPLEMENTATION.

Comment: I get the idea, but I'll simply set line = NULL, to avoiding doing malloc + strcpy in loop. Thanks (: